# How to create a div container with equal spacing on child divs

Tags: html, css, containers

I want to create a div that holds other div, like a little menu of sorts.  I want the spacing between the inner div and the container to be the same on all sides.  How do I do this?  So far I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: rgba(0,127,255,.5);
    }
    .child {
        margin-top: 5px;
        background-color: rgba(255,127,0,.5);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">Foo</div>
    <div class="child">Bar</div>
    <div class="child">Gaz</div>
    <div class="child">Waka</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, this leaves a 10px space between the top element and the container, but only a 5px space between the bottom element and the container.  When I remove the top padding from the container, there are 0px of space between the container top and the first element.  How do I get this space to be even on all sides?

Update:

One solution is to remove the top padding from the container, and set its display to inline-block and set the width to 100%, and the html and body to have 0 margin and padding.  However, this makes the children all flush with the right side of the windows, and no right padding.  How to I accomplish this with even spacing and padding and the container flush with the side of the windows?

```
<html class="page">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    html,body { 
        padding: 0px; 
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .container {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        background-color: rgba(0,127,255,.5);
    }
    .child {
        margin-top: 5px;
        background-color: rgba(255,127,0,.5);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">Foo</div>
    <div class="child">Bar</div>
    <div class="child">Gaz</div>
    <div class="child">Waka</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just cancel the margin for the first child?

like this:

```
.child:first-child {margin:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vfcjwqy7/

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  JSG also suggested this.  This CSS worked nicely, `html, body {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
  } 
  .container {
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: rgba(0,127,255,.5);
  }
  .child {
   margin-top: 5px;
   background-color: rgba(255,127,0,.5);
  }
  .child:first-child {
      margin-top:0;
  }`  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your css:

```
.child:first-child{
    margin-top:0;
}
```

It should remove the margin top from the first element.

Answer (score 0):

use the below simple css code:

```
.child {
/* margin-top: 5px; */
background-color: rgba(255,127,0,.5);
padding: 10px 0;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [adjacent siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
.child { background-color: rgba(255,127,0,.5); }
.child + .child { margin-top: 5px; }
```